# Compile error: unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, member-pointers

I try to compile the following with g++ 4.7.2:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    struct B {
        T t;

        template<T B::*M>
        T get() {
            return this->*M;
        }
    };

    B b;

    T get() {
        return b.get<&B::t>();
    }
};


int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.get();
}
```

It gives me

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘T A<T>::get()’:
test.cpp:15:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T A<T>::get() [with T = int]’:
test.cpp:22:8:   required from here
test.cpp:15:23: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int A<int>::B::*’ to binary ‘operator<’
```

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the `template` disambiguator:

```
return b.template get<&B::t>();
```

Without it, when parsing the expression:

```
b.get<&B::t>();
```

The compiler can't tell whether it should interpret `get` as the name of a member variable followed by a `<` sign (less-than), or as the instantiation of a member function template called `get`.

Although *we* know what is the intended meaning of our expression, the compiler cannot, at least not before instantiation occurs - and syntactic parsing is performed even though your function is never instantiated.

Comment: And just when you know C++... When I am I supposed to use "template disambiguation"? (I just searched, but I can't seem to find a good answer on this.)

Comment: @PaulDraper: Actually, I found [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) which should explain it quite well.

Comment: Excellent. That also includes the explanation for `typename`, which I have also not fully understood.